# azure logic apps iteration control

Tags: azure

i am using logic app to process batch of records. lets say i started to process 1000 records with batch of each 500.i put the condition in untill loop that till all records (1000) processed keep running untill loop. the first it pick up 500 records and start processing that . during processing of first 500 records if any network issue or other issue occured then its coming out of until loop and left anothr batch of 500 records.
my question is how can i continue another batch of 500 records if even first batch of 500 records gets failed?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that works is to change the flow from using until flow to just using the batch messages trigger mentioning the message count. So that the mentioned number of messages will be batched and released at once in your case it will be 500.

[image]

Comment: this seems to irrelevant to my questions. my concern is lets say we have two batch of records each with 500, in first until loop first 500 records start processing and its gets failed because of some network or other issues, then in this case it should continue with another batch of 500 records instead of getting come out of untill loop

Comment: @YahyaShareef, Apologies for confusion, Please try checking the updated answer.